# In python, what does this ' return decorator(callback) if callback else decorator ' mean?

Tags: python, return, if-statement

```
def method(path,method,callback) 
    def decorator(callback):if isinstance(callback, basestring): callback = load(callback)
        for rule in makelist(path) or yieldroutes(callback):
            for verb in makelist(method):
                verb = verb.upper()
                route = Route(self, rule, verb, callback, name=name,
                              plugins=plugins, skiplist=skiplist, **config)
                self.add_route(route)
    return callback
return decorator(callback) if callback else decorator
```

what's the meaning of the last sentence?

Comment: There's a published language standard, and an interactive interpreter. You'll get more joy looking basic questions up before you post them here.

Answer (score 5):

```
return decorator(callback) if callback else decorator
```

translates into:

```
if callback:
   return decorator(callback)
else:
   return decorator
```

It's [Python's way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator#Python) of having a [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator) expression.

See this SO question for more information on the [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator)
.

Comment: @user1092988 If this answered your question please feel free to [accept this answer by clicking the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) next to this answer. It'll reward us both with some points and mark this problem as solved.

Answer (score 0):

The last sentence basically means

```
if callback:  # Tests to see if callback is not None in essence, although 0 and '' will also test False
    return decorator(callback)
else:    # Not needed, just for clarity sake
    return decorator
```